# Why can't I set -ms-transform with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

This is the code for my entire page. The div is rotated in Firefox (as expected), but not in IE9. Setting the -ms-transform property using normal CSS makes the div rotate, so the problem seems to stem from the attempt to set the property using jQuery. Does anyone know what's going on?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script>    
    $(function(){
        $("#divid").css("-ms-transform", "rotate(-90deg)");   // For IE9
        $("#divid").css("-moz-transform", "rotate(-90deg)");  // For Firefox
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divid">Foo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your doctype <!DOCTYPE html> not broken?? can you check if that is the start of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can! :-)

```
$('#divid').css({ msTransform: 'rotate(-90deg)' }); // for IE9
```

Very relevant [IE9: Why setting "-ms-transform" works from css, but not with jquery.css()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594117/ie9-why-setting-ms-transform-works-from-css-but-not-with-jquery-css)

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to use a CSS Class for this:

```
.rotated {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

------

jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#divid').addClass('rotated');
});
```

Comment: For compatibility with webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) you may add "-webkit-transform"

Comment: @Bakudan, yes, obviously you can add whatever styles you need for your target browsers into the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This might be relevant: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8346

The one reporting it got around with using [jQuery.cssHooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/):

```
jQuery.cssHooks["MsTransform"] = {
    set: function( elem, value ) {
        elem.style.msTransform = value;
    }
};

$("#divid").css("MsTransform", "rotate(-90deg)");
```