# How to appendChild to an array of images with specific height and width

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm trying to append the title of each image of an array to each individual image who's height and width are greater than x

*Couldn't figure out how to format this correctly with the editor

```
var curHeight;
var curWidth;
var hr;
function imgHr(){
  var allImages = document.images;
   for (var i=0; allImages.length > i; i++) {
     var imgSrc = allImages[i].src;
     var newImg = new Image();
     newImg.src = imgSrc;    
     curHeight = newImg.height;
     curWidth = newImg.width;
      if(curWidth>='80' && curHeight>='80'){
         var imgGet=allImages[i];
         var hrT=allImages[i].title;
         var hr= document.createElement("hr");
         hr.style.border-bottom="1px solid skyblue";
         hr.innerHTML=hrT;
         //appendChild isn't working
         imgGet.appendChild(hr);
         //but everthing else works: example
         imgGet.style.border="1px solid red";
       } else {
         //maybe add something later
       }
    }   
 }
```

OK this solved my case

```
function insertafter(newChild, refChild){ 
 refChild.parentNode.insertBefore(newChild,refChild.nextSibling);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in `hr.style.border-bottom="1px solid skyblue"`. In javascript you need to use camelCase properties: `hr.style.borderBottom="1px solid skyblue"`. See [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594117/ie9-why-setting-ms-transform-works-from-css-but-not-with-jquery-css/5594170#5594170).

Furthermore, you can't use `appendChild` on an `img` element. You'll have to wrap the image in a `div` (so: create a `div` element, append the `img` to that, remove the `img` from it's original position, create a `hr` element, append it to the `div`).

Last but not least: you can't use `innerHTML` with a `h(orizontal)r(uler)`. So what remains is: create a `div` element, append the `img` to that <sup>**1**</sup>, remove the `img` from it's original position, create a textNode (or a span) containing the img title, and append that to the `div`.

<sup>**1**</sup> another idea may be to use the image as a background image for the newly created `div`.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing that out. But the appendChild is still not working.

Comment: so appendChild will try to nest the new element inside of the img element? So I would need to use jQuery's (.after) to achieve this without adding addition div elements?

Comment: I see no other way to do this without using jQuery. Your method would have worked to, but i'd rather not manually wrap div elements around my large base of images. Thanks for making that clear

Comment: Hi Tj, edited some more, as it occured to me that you were trying to use `innerHTML` for a `hr` element. I never use JQuery, so can't tell if it's more applicable in this case.

Comment: Actually my aim was to append the new element (<h1>title</h1>) after the image. but this can't be achieved in javascript alone. *sorry the horizontal rule was meant to be a header element (h1). I confused my self by using the hr(for header) as the variable.But thanks again