# Rotation property not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to rotate a div element in IE8 browser.

I have rendered the arrow (with two div elements)

```
<DIV class=e-arrowTip> 
 <DIV class=e-arrowTipOuter></DIV>
 <DIV class=e-arrowTipInner></DIV>
</DIV>

.e-arrowTip{
    bottom: -1px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)";
    filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)";
    left: 50%;
    top: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 20px;
}
```

In IE8, the div element not rotated.

Comment: I forget to say one thing,  I am applying the styles through the scripting $(.e-arrowTip).css({"-ms-filter" : "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0)"})

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `.e-arrowTip`:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

UPDATE:

Change `.css({"-ms-filter" :` to `.css({"msFilter" :`

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594170/704808